# Gentoo invalid profile

Tags: gentoo, profile, livecd, emerge, portage

So. Been going at the gentoo install without proper instructions until very recently. After `emerge-webrsync` stage of the install a message pops up saying "your current profile is invalid". It appears to be a blocker on emerging to kick off the rest of the install.

This doesn't seem to be an issue with the laptop (NIC is working and changing ssd does nothing for this issue) and I've validated the SHA-512 against the `DIGEST.asc` associated with the downloaded tarball. It seems unlikely the livecd I'm using to install would have been rewritten over this network connection. `eselect` is functioning, and experimentation with the 35 defaults yields no results. Have created a custom profile but am having issues having it appear on `eselect`. Confused somewhat on the documentation for this, continuing to experiment. Suggestions welcome.

Have already run `eselect profile list` and `eselect profile set` for the default profiles.

The issue persists after an `emerge --sync`.

In fact the issue first occurred after an `emerge --sync`.

Have `readlink`'d the `make.profile` in portage and tried a few different symlinks.
Resources:

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Profile_(Portage)
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Eselect/User_guide
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/User:Sakaki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Installing_the_Gentoo_Stage_3_Files

Answer (score 0):

Run `eselect profile list` and then `eselect proflile set <num>` to select one.

Comment: As `eselect profile` didn't help, try running `emerge --sync` to populate `/usr/portage` maybe?

Comment: Few extra steps there: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened_Gentoo#Switching_to_a_Hardened_profile

Comment: It seems as though the profile issue *could* be resolved by nano-ing around on the livecd. Would it be wise to ask for some form of hint here?

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by replacing NIC card. Used different network connection as well.